# Create a custom object referencing other objects

Tags: powershell, amazon-web-services, tagging, psobject

I am trying to create a new custom object with data input from another object.

```
$clusters = Get-EMRClusters 
$runningclusters = $clusters | Where-Object {
    $_.Status.State -eq "Running" -or
    $_.Status.State -eq "Waiting"
}
```

`$runningclusters` looks like

```
id            name        status
--            ----        ------
j-12345       cluster1    running
j-4567        cluster2    running
```

I want to create a new PSobject `$o` with a 4th column named `PendingShutdown` that's a boolean.

```
id            name        status    pendingshutdown
--            ----        ------    ---------------
j-12345       cluster1    running   False
j-4567        cluster2    running   False
```

I have tried running this:

```
$o = New-Object PSObject
$o | Add-Member -NotePropertyName id -NotePropertyValue $runningclusters.id
$o | Add-Member -NotePropertyName name -NotePropertyValue $runningclusters.name
$o | Add-Member -NotePropertyName status -NotePropertyValue $runningclusters.status.state
$o | Add-Member -NotePropertyName PendingShutdown -NotePropertyValue $true
```

But my output for `$o` for the columns `id` and `name` are just objects themselves, not rows of IDs. How do I make an object to look like my desired object above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to loop through each of the cluster-objects. You can loop through them and add the column to the current object, like:

```
$runningclusters = $clusters |
Where-Object {$_.Status.State -eq "Running" -or $_.Status.State -eq "Waiting"} |
Add-Member -NotePropertyName pendingshutdown -NotePropertyValue $true -PassThru
```

Or you could create new objects per cluster. Ex:

```
$MyNewClusterObjects = $runningclusters | ForEach-Object {
    New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property @{
        id = $_.id
        name = $_.name
        status = $_.status.state
        PendingShutdown = $true
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! For the second method, the columns are returned in the order of `status,pendingshutdown, name, id`  not the desired order of `id, name, status, pendingshutdown`. Is there a way to make the object match the row of the orders specified?

Comment: Create the hashtable as an [ordered hashtable](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39521208/1630171) before creating the object.

Comment: As Ansgar said... or change the last line to `} | Select-Object id, name, status, pendingshutdown`

Answer (score 2):

Simply use [calculated properties](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx) for adding properties to objects in a pipeline, e.g. like this:

```
$runningclusters = $clusters | Where-Object {
    $_.Status.State -eq "Running" -or
    $_.Status.State -eq "Waiting"
} | Select-Object *,@{n='PendingShutdown';e={$false}}
```