# Property has a value but cannot select it

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-5.0, type-accelerators

I have a function that checks the registry for an uninstall key called Get-InstalledApps

```
Function Get-InstalledApps {
    param (
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
        [string[]]$ComputerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME,
        [string]$NameRegex = ''
    )

    foreach ($comp in $ComputerName) {
        $keys = '','\Wow6432Node'
        foreach ($key in $keys) {
            try {
                $reg = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey('LocalMachine', $comp)
                $apps = $reg.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE$key\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall").GetSubKeyNames()
            } catch {
                continue
            }

            foreach ($app in $apps) {
                $program = $reg.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE$key\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\$app")
                $name = $program.GetValue('DisplayName')
                if ($name -and $name -match $NameRegex) {
                    [pscustomobject]@{
                        ComputerName = $comp
                        DisplayName = $name
                        DisplayVersion = $program.GetValue('DisplayVersion')
                        Publisher = $program.GetValue('Publisher')
                        InstallDate = $program.GetValue('InstallDate')
                        UninstallString = $program.GetValue('UninstallString')
                        Bits = $(if ($key -eq '\Wow6432Node') {'64'} else {'32'})
                        Path = $program.name
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and then I grab the DisplayName/Version for what I need. My current problem is that it only seems to work on certain machines. Example:

```
Get-InstalledApps | Where-Object {$_.Displayname -like "*Citrix Receiver*"}

Name                           Value
----                           -----
InstallDate
ComputerName                   Computer
DisplayName                    Citrix Receiver 4.7
Bits                           64
UninstallString                C:\ProgramData\Citrix\Citrix Receiver 4.7\TrolleyExpress.exe /uninstall /cleanup
Path                           HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\CitrixOnlinePluginPackWeb
Publisher                      Citrix Systems, Inc.                                                              
DisplayVersion                 14.7.0.13011
```

So this is great, I get what I want. Now I normally just pipe in `| Select-Object Displayname -ExpandProperty Displayname` and it would return `"Citrix Receiver 4.7"` just like I want. My problem is that on certain machines I'm getting this:

```
Get-InstalledApps | Where-Object {$_.Displayname -like "*Citrix Receiver*"} | Select-Object DisplayName

DisplayName
-----------
```

And that's it. Why is there no value listed? If I try to `expandproperty` I get an error because it says nothing is there, but clearly there is something there or the `Where-Object` would not have found it in my search. Again, in a lot cases this code works just fine and I get the value I want but on a lot of machines I'm getting what you see above.

Edited in from comments:

I run this on a user's machine and I get the results I posted. If I run it on my machine I'll get the value "Citrix Receiver 4.7" every time. Also, on my machine I don't get the Name and Value columns. Only about 1/4 of the machines I ran this code on actually gave me the value I expected. Windows 7 vs Windows 10 thing?

Comment: Well, the obvious question would be to ask if there is an uninstall key for citrix on that machine or not?

Comment: Well yeah, it returns the Property and Value but I cannot select the Value for some reason.

Comment: According to the example that you have shown it probably is not returning the property value. Select will add properties to an object. For instance if you run this code: **'' | Select Foo** you will see a Foo property with no value

Comment: You are showing some effects of your function but not its code.

Comment: Yes, seeing what the function is doing (and hence what it is really returning) would certainly help.

Comment: Added the function. By the way, you were correct: | Select Foo returned a property with no value. Hopefully the function code will give some more insight, apologies for being a little ignorant here. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like your function returns a `[hashtable]`, but you're using it like it's an object with properties.

That happens to work fine with `Where-Object` because the `.Member` syntax works for accessing `[hashtable]` values, but it's not going to work with `Select-Object` because it's operating on actual properties.

So what can you do?

If you want to keep it as a `[hashtable]`, and insist on doing it in a pipeline, you can use `ForEach-Object`:

```
Get-InstalledApps | 
    Where-Object {$_.Displayname -like "*Citrix Receiver*"} |
    ForEach-Object -Process { $_.DisplayName }
```

or

```
Get-InstalledApps | 
    Where-Object {$_.Displayname -like "*Citrix Receiver*"} |
    ForEach-Object -MemberName Item -ArgumentList DisplayName
```

Another thing you can do is change your function to return an object.

This is really easy to do with a `[hashtable]`; so say your function is about to return `$hash`, instead return:

```
New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $hash
```

Now you can use the normal suite of cmdlets and have them work as expected.

---

**Edit:** after seeing your code, it looks like you are converting your hashtable to an object already, but your output says otherwise. It wouldn't display as `Name` and `Value` columns if that were the case, so I still think something is wrong and the output is a `[hashtable]`.

**Edit 2:** with info from comments about the platform differences, this seems to be happening because the object conversion is being done with the [`[pscustomobject]` type accelerator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35894272/3905079) which was added in PowerShell v3. Since the problematic machine is running Windows 7, it may be running v2 (which is what Win 7 shipped with).

Recommendations:

1. Get rid of Windows 7.
2. If you can't do that, upgrade PowerShell (Windows Management Framework) on that machine.
3. Either way, use `New-Object` as posted above.

Comment: The function definitely returns customobjects

Comment: Yeah and this is where I'm confused. I run this on a user's machine and I get the results I posted. If I run it on my machine I'll get the value "Citrix Receiver 4.7" every time. Also, on my machine I don't get the Name and Value columns. Only about 1/4 of the machines I ran this code on actually gave me the value I expected. Windows 7 vs Windows 10 thing?

Comment: My first suspicion would be a 64bit/32bit thing

Comment: @noz3r0 yes, most likely due to the platform difference. `[pscustomobject]` was not available in PowerShell 2.0, which is the version that shipped with Windows 7. My method using `New-Object` would work on 2.0+ though. I'm guessing somewhere the error is being swallowed and the hashtable is getting returned instead.

Comment: @EBGreen `The function definitely returns customobjects` yes the fucntion as posted, when run on a version that supports the `[pscustomobject]` accelerator does return them, and it works as expected, but the output he shows in the question does not match object output, it matches `[hashtable]` output.

Comment: Yep, that would certainly explain it. I always use New-Object anyway out of habit so I've never seen this issue.

Comment: Alright so that's definitely the issue, a lot of machines have just PS2.0 Do you mind explaining how I would modify the function correctly to make the table using New-Object? I'm a bit novice still with Powershell. Thanks again for all the help so far!

Comment: @noz3r0 already in my answer. Just pass the `[hashtable]` (literally or as a variable) to the `-Property` parameter.