# Powershell - Cannot convert value of type "System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject" to type "System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject"

Tags: powershell, type-conversion, powershell-4.0, powershell-cmdlet

I am working with Powershell 4 under Windows 7 and I have cmdlet defined like this:

```
 Function Transfer-File {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject]
        $source,

        # other parameters removed for brevity
    )

    # actual logic does not matter 

  }
```

I am calling it like this:

```
$hasError = Transfer-File -source $source -destination $cfg.Destination -logfile $logFile
```

$source is obtained by parsing a JSON file and looks like this:

```
@{Path=some path string here; Pack=False}
```

`Write-Host $source.GetType()` outputs:

```
System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject
```

I obtain the following error:

> Cannot convert the "@{Path=some path string here; Pack=False}"
>   value of type "System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject" to type
>   "System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject".

In a desperate trial to solve it empirically I replace `System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject` with `psobject` and it seems to work fine.

**Question:** Why does my `System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject` does not seem to fit `System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject` from the cmdlet prototype?

---

Complete code for object creation:

```
### Configuration ###
$cfg = New-Object –TypeName PSObject
$cfg | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty –Name Sources –Value @()

# get configuration from json file
$jsonContent = Get-Content .\config.json |  Out-String
$jsonObj = ConvertFrom-Json $jsonContent
$cfg.Sources = $jsonObj.Sources

Foreach ($source in $cfg.Sources)
{
    # Write-Host $source.GetType()
    $hasError = Transfer-File -source $source -destination $cfg.Destination -logfile $logFile
}
```

Comment: Check [this](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/2295) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35894272/powershell-type-accelerators-psobject-vs-pscustomobject) link out!

Comment: How did you create `$source` object? Via `New-Object`?

Comment: `[System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject]` is a singleton object, instance of which is used to represent the fact, that there are no meaningful base object in `[System.Management.Automation.PSObject]`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @VivekKumarSingh's comment suggests, this is a [bug](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/2295) related to the accelerator.

This will not work:

```
# Error
$y = [System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject]@{Path='some path string here'; Pack=$False}
```

And this will not work:

```
$y = [PSCustomObject]@{Path='some path string here'; Pack=$False}

function t ([System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject]$x) { $x }

# Error
t $y
```

This will work:

```
$y = [PSCustomObject]@{Path='some path string here'; Pack=$False}

function t ([PSCustomObject]$x) { $x }

t $y
```

However, the above will *not* type cast anything to a `PSCustomObject`, because that type inherits from `Object`:

```
PS> function t ([PSCustomObject]$x) { $x.GetType().FullName }
PS> t 5
System.Int32
PS> t 'asdf'
System.String
PS> t $(Get-ChildItem)
System.Object[]
PS> t $(Get-Item .)
System.IO.DirectoryInfo
```

This will also work, but I'm not entirely sure if it's 100% equivalent.

```
function t ([System.Management.Automation.PSObject]$x) { $x }
```

The reason I'm not sure is because of this weirdness:

```
PS> $a = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSObject -Property @{Path='some path string here'; Pack=$False}
PS> $a.GetType().FullName
System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject

PS> $a = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject -Property @{Path='some path string here'; Pack=$False}
New-Object : A constructor was not found. Cannot find an appropriate constructor for type System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject.

PS> $a = [PSCustomObject]@{Path='some path string here'; Pack=$False}
PS> $a.GetType().FullName
System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject

PS> $a = [System.Management.Automation.PSObject]@{Path='some path string here'; Pack=$False}
PS> $a.GetType().FullName
System.Collections.Hashtable

PS> $a = [PSObject]@{Path='some path string here'; Pack=$False}
PS> $a.GetType().FullName
System.Collections.Hashtable
```

As far as I know, `[PSCustomObject]` and `[PSObject]` are both accelerators for `System.Management.Automation.PSObject`. `System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject` is just an implementation detail they added to make `[PSCustomObject]` possible, but, unfortunately, the way that everything works feels a bit inconsistent. I'm not entirely clear on what the `[PSObject]` type accelerator is for, however. It appears to do nothing, but it also certainly exists:

```
PS> ([System.Management.Automation.Cmdlet]).Assembly.GetType('System.Management.Automation.TypeAccelerators')::Get.ContainsKey('psobject')
True
```